# Entropy as "extent of energy dispersal" vs. entropy as defined by the Clausius equation

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, entropy

Currently, the concept of entropy as "energy dispersal" has been proved to be more easy to understand than the concept of "disorder". While the first can be applied successfully to explain the expansion of a gas through vacuum, I don't get how the temperature influences the "energy spreading" according to the Clausius equation (although this is simple to understand with the concept of "disorder"):
$$dS = \frac{dq_{rev}}{T}$$
If the temperature is low, the energy added to the system ($dq_{rev}$) increase its entropy ($dS$) more than if the temperature is high. How this can be explained applying the "energy dispersal" interpretation?

Comment: You don't understand a concept.  Ok.  What is the question?

Comment: @Lighthart, why do you think I don't understand entropy?

Comment: I thought that is what you stated. My apologies for misconstruing you words.